# Simplify finding indices of all instances of certain characters in a string

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, guava

I have a string util method for finding potential "wrapping points" in a string.

For example, if `" "` and `"-"` are considered wrapping chars, then for input string
 `"Antoni Gil-Bao"` the method would return the sorted set `[6, 10]`.

```
private static final String WRAPPING_CHARS = " -";
private static final CharMatcher WRAP_CHAR_MATCHER = CharMatcher.anyOf(WRAPPING_CHARS);

public static SortedSet<Integer> findWrappingIndices(String s) {
    SortedSet<Integer> indices = Sets.newTreeSet();
    while (WRAP_CHAR_MATCHER.indexIn(s) != -1) {
        int index = WRAP_CHAR_MATCHER.indexIn(s);
        int indexInOriginalString = indices.isEmpty() ? index :  index + indices.last() + 1;
        indices.add(indexInOriginalString);    
        s = s.substring(index + 1);
    }
    return indices;
}
```

Question is, **is there a simpler way to implement this method using Guava**? (Besides trivialities like inlining `indexInOriginalString`.) Based on my unit tests, the above does the job, but it doesn't feel that elegant. Obviously **pure Java** solutions are welcome too, if they are simpler than my Guava version. In any case, the method should take a `String` and return `SortedSet<Integer>`.

(Background: the reason I just want the indices, instead of doing any string wrapping here directly, is that eventually I'll be operating inside [onDraw()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29), on a char array, and I want to [*measure*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) pieces of text in the actual font before making wrapping decisions.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two inefficiencies in your code:

- You call `.indexIn()` twice in quick succession.  You should have saved the return value from the first call.
- You create a substring with each iteration.  [Starting with Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16123446/1157100), that would be a performance problem, since each substring is a copy of part of the original string.

Also, it would be no additional work for you to generalize the method to accept any `CharSequence`.

```
public static SortedSet<Integer> findWrappingIndices(CharSequence s) {
    SortedSet<Integer> indices = Sets.newTreeSet();
    for (int i = -1; -1 != (i = WRAP_CHAR_MATCHER.indexIn(s, i + 1)); ) {
        indices.add(i);    
    }
    return indices;
}
```

Another option, using just the built-in Java library, would be to use a regex, with `[- ]` as the pattern.

Answer (score 4):

`Simplify` is a relative term. If you want simple, then I would have:

```
public static int[] findWrappingIndices(final String s) {
    int pos = 0;
    int[] ret = new int[s.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (WRAPPING_CHARS.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) >= 0) {
            ret[pos++] = i;
        }
    }
    return Arrays.copyOf(ret, pos);
}
```

But, you want to complexify it by using a SortedSet (because int[] is not easy to use?), so you can then convert the int[] to the SortedSet.

I don't see why the SortedSet is a good idea, but, it is easy enough to convert to using it (even though it is bigger and slower than an int[] array).

I don't think you will find a simpler (or faster) alternative.

I would guess that you could quavify it with (note the data is being inserted in sorted order anyway):

```
public static SortedSet<Integer> findWrappingIndices(final String s) {
    SortedSet<Integer> indices = Sets.newTreeSet();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (WRAPPING_CHARS.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) >= 0) {
            indices.add(i);
        }
    }
    return indices;
}
```

Comment: I prefer collections over arrays whenever possible, as they provide a friendlier and more powerful API to work with. In this particular case however (rather low-level string handling), a plain old `int[]` could indeed be fine. Anyway, +1 for demonstrating that in this case Guava doesn't make the solution any simpler compared to pure Java.

Comment: By the way, the reason I used SortedSet was not sorting, but the fact that it best describes the returned data and makes it very easy *for the user of the method* to e.g. find next wrapping index for any arbitrary index: `indices.tailSet(i + 1).first()`. To be able to call `tailSet()` the return type must be SortedSet, regardless of implementation details like whether the data was already ordered.